# mysql inner joins query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

having problems with the following inner joins query on my products table -->>

```
SELECT   products.prod_id, products.prod_name, products.price, suppliers.company_name, customers.phone,
     FROM products
     INNER JOIN suppliers
     ON suppliers.supp_id = suppliers.supp_ID;
```

Comment: One side of the = or the other should be products rather than them both being suppliers.

Comment: That query won't even compile because you have an extra comma at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining on `suppliers.supp_id = suppliers.supp_ID;`

Both from the suppliers table... you want an attribute from the product table. Something like:

```
products.supp_id = suppliers.supp_ID;
```

Which will result in the following query:

```
    SELECT   
       products.prod_id, 
       products.prod_name, 
       products.price, 
       suppliers.company_name, 
       customers.phone
    FROM 
       products
    INNER JOIN 
       suppliers
    ON 
       products.supp_id = suppliers.supp_ID;
```

Comment: still getting the error ---->

SQL query: Documentation


SELECT   products.prod_id, products.prod_name, products.price, suppliers.company_name, customers.phone,
     FROM products
     INNER JOIN suppliers
     ON products.supp_id = suppliers.supp_ID
 LIMIT 0, 30 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM products
     INNER JOIN suppliers
     ON products.supp_id = suppliers.sup' at line 2

Comment: @Jmac88 remove the comma (',') at the end of the select statement (before the FROM). Updated the Answer with the complete query.